# Why is this PendingIntent not returning null after canceling?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

In the same function call, I try create a pending intent, cancel it, then check if it has been cancelled. The following is my snippet:

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        sender.cancel();
        PendingIntent senderUpdated = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

I expect senderUpdate to be null, but it is not. The intent, alarmId, context are all the same variables.